# jQuery fadeOut wait for the effect to finish before starting new one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am making few info boxes and have jquery UI clip effect combined with fadeIn/fadeOut. 
The problem is that email fade out is not finishing if you leave the box to fast. 
I used the callback but it is either my mouseleave that is affecting it or ?

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/6euyze8k/1/

```
jQuery(".holder").each(function (index, element) {
    var infos = jQuery(this).find('.info,.socials');
    var docmail = jQuery(this).find('.email');

    jQuery(this).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            infos.show("clip", function () {
                docmail.fadeIn(500);
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            docmail.fadeOut(500, function () {
                infos.hide("clip");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have made that could fit with your problem:

```
jQuery(".holder").each(function (index, element) {
    var $el = jQuery(this);
    var infos = $el.find('.info,.socials');
    var docmail = $el.find('.email');
    $el.data('endEnter', false);
    $el.data('endLeave', true);

    $el.on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            if($el.data('endLeave')) {
                infos.show("clip", function () {
                    docmail.fadeIn(500, function() {
                         $el.data('endEnter', true);
                        $el.data('endLeave', false);
                    });
                });
            }

        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if($el.data('endEnter')) {
                docmail.fadeOut(500, function () {
                    infos.hide("clip", function() {
                         $el.data('endLeave', true);
                        $el.data('endEnter', false);
                    });
                });
            }

        }
    });
});
```

The idea is to not allow fire the events until animation ends, but *clip* animation made some problems with that if you move the cursor quickly in & out of the element.

Anymway, check it out here:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/Lchpon4x/

Good luck!

Comment: thnx but it has a bit bigger issue than mine. if hovered to fast everything stays there. http://prntscr.com/4td8ee